# How add soap header in response (NodeJS y Strong-soap)

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, header, strong-soap

I am using strong-soap as server in node js, i need a pass throught service to convert xml to json (soap call to rest call, i used asyn method) but i need to respond soap incoming request with a response with headers.

I used the async function providen by documentation.

```
var myService = {
      MyService: {
          MyPort: {

              // This is how to define an asynchronous function, i can get the incoming headers but i dont send the response with headers.
              MyAsyncFunction: function(args, callback, headers) {
                  // do some work
                  callback({
                      name: args.name
                  });
              },

          }
      }
  };
```

incoming soap request (body and headers) ->
soap response (body and headers) <-

How can i do this?

I am searching about this but i did not find nothing.
I tried sending another parameter to the callback function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set headers using node-soap in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659705/how-to-set-headers-using-node-soap-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

The response was...

```js
const server = soap.listen(...);

const addResponseSoapHeaders = (headers: string | Object) => {
  // We need to clear previous headers (Headers in response will be accumulated from previous responses if we dont clear)
  server.clearSoapHeaders();
  // Add Headers to response
  server.addSoapHeader(headers);
}
```